# C# / Compact Framework 2.0 / List query error

Tags: c#, .net, list, compact-framework

OK so I have:

```
var filteredItems = lstAllItems.Where(item => item.Parent.ID == parentId);

TreeNode childNode;
    foreach (var i in filteredItems.ToList())
    {
        if (parentNode == null)
            childNode = tvwPickList.Nodes.Add(i.Text);
        else
            childNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(i.Text);

        RefreshPickList(i.ID, childNode);
    }
```

This is throwing some errors at me:

Warning 1   Reference to type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\mscorlib.dll', but it could not be found   c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll  IMSCF

Error   2   The type 'System.Data.DataTable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.   C:\Data\C#\IMSCF\IMSCF\frmPickList.cs   52  13  IMSCF

Error   3   The type 'System.Data.DataRow' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Data\C#\IMSCF\IMSCF\frmPickList.cs   52  13  IMSCF

The 'var' keywords get highlighted by the last two errors.

I'm pretty new to C# and .NET CF so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here; the code is adapted from something I found on a C# site somewhere.

Funny thing is, those references do exist in my project...all the right using statements are there etc...

Is there something here that .NET CF doesn't support (that's becoming a recurring theme in this project :P)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using features of .net cf 3.5. Your headline says you're using .net cf 2.0. That's causing your problems.

More specifically:

1. the `Where` method is part of LINQ. LINQ was introduced with .net cf 3.5.
2. Lamba Expressions require .net cf 3.5
3. Also, the `var` keyword is not part of .net 2.0.

So: either use .net cf 3.5 (recommended) or only use what 2.0 can handle.

(There's probably a technically better way  to put it, but it boils down to 2.0 vs. 3.5)

EDIT: How to upgrade to 3.5:
In Visual Studio 2008 select *Project* from the menu, click on *Upgrade Project* and click *Yes*. That should be it.

Comment: Yeah I just figured that var thing out. I need to be on 2.0 due to the device itself; I've found another way that works.

Comment: Glad it helped. Are you sure about having to stick to 2.0? What device would that be? You can install .net 3.5 on Pocket PC 2003, Windows Mobile 5.0+, Windows CE .NET 5.0+. So, unless you've got an pre2003 device, you should be able to install .net 3.5 on it. (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e3821449-3c6b-42f1-9fd9-0041345b3385) I'd like to encurage you to doublecheck that constraint.

Comment: It's a Honeywell Dolphin 6100 barcode scanner - the scanner SDK doesn't seem to agree with NETCF 3.5 according to their tech support. I'm nearly finished with it on 2.0 and all seems well so far anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've a class library and the Windows Mobile application?

If so, have you checked that your class library has been created with the right Visual Studio template?

You'll need to create such class library with Mobile Visual Studio-installed templates, because it seems that you did with the regular C# class library one, which adds namespaces that aren't pressent in CF.

Another thing you may check is maybe your Windows Mobile forms project is CF 3.5 while your class library is 2.0. Go to both project properties and check that target framework equals (you'd be using CF 3.5!!).